# User defined function and stream aggregator in DolphinDB

Tags: dolphindb

I want to use a user defined function in stream aggregator in DolphinDB.

However it returns an exception and I have no idea how to deal with it:

```
def mymid(vec){
    return (first(vec) + last(vec))/2
}
share streamTable(10000:0, `time`device`metric, [TIMESTAMP, SYMBOL, DOUBLE] as sensor
output = table(10000:0, `time`mymid, [TIMESTAMP, DOUBLE]);
aggregator = createStreamAggregator("aggregator", 120, 60, <mymid(metric)>, sensor, output, `time)


execution was completed with exception
Usage: createStreamAggregator(name, windowSize, step, metrics, dummyTable, outputTable, timeColumn, [useSystemTime=false], [keyColumn], [garbageSize]). 
the outermost meta code must be aggregated functions.
```

Obviously `mymid` is an aggregated function. My question is how to create an aggregated user defined function in DolphinDB?

Answer (score 0):

Use keyword `defg` instead of keyword `def` to represent an aggregated function

```
defg mymid(vec){
    return (first(vec) + last(vec))/2
}
```